# Laravel elements in queue are processed multiple times

Tags: php, laravel, supervisord

We use the Laravel Redis Queue and a supervisor setup with multiple parallel running workers. Sometimes it happens that one element in the queue get processed multiple times.

Is there a trick, like a flag i can set or something else to avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the job messages become available for other consumers.

> In your config/queue.php configuration file, each queue connection
>   defines a retry_after option. This option specifies how many seconds
>   the queue connection should wait before retrying a job that is being
>   processed. For example, if the value of retry_after is set to 90, the
>   job will be released back onto the queue if it has been processing for
>   90 seconds without being deleted. Typically, you should set the
>   retry_after value to the maximum number of seconds your jobs should reasonably take to complete processing.

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#queue-workers-and-deployment

When a consumer receives and processes a message from a queue, the message remains in the queue. The queue doesn’t automatically delete the message. Because a queue is a distributed system, there’s no guarantee that the consumer actually receives the message (for example, due to a connectivity issue, or due to an issue in the consumer application). Therefore, the consumer must delete the message from the queue after receiving and processing it. Immediately after a message is received, it remains in the queue. To prevent other consumers from processing the message again, you should set the `retry_after` value to the maximum number of seconds your jobs should reasonably take to complete processing.

**For Amazon SQS:**

The only queue connection which does not contain a `retry_after` value is SQS. SQS will retry the job based on the Default Visibility Timeout which is managed within the AWS console. Amazon SQS sets a visibility timeout, a period of time during which Amazon SQS prevents other consumers from receiving and processing the message. The default visibility timeout for a message is 30 seconds.This means that other consumers can see and pickup the message again after 30 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

If there is an exception or the job inexplicably fails, the job will automatically be retried. This will occur even if most of the job has already ran.

Comment: Curiosly i havent any exceptions in the log.
I'm going to use the failed function to revert the process on failing.